# Drupal 7 Views 3 exposed filter preselected

Tags: views

I'm having a bit of a hard time configuring a preselected exposed filter on views.

I have a View `(mysite.com/view-path)` with an exposed filter as a select list with options:

```
Option 1
Option 2
Option 3
```

I want to be able to access the view with a preselected option in the exposed filter from another page `(mysite.com/page)` with a link like so `(mysite.com/view-path?option=1)`

Right now i've made a form alter on the exposed view filter with this:

```
if (!empty($_GET['option'])) {
   $form_state['input']['field_option_tid'] = $_GET['option'];
}
```

The problem is that this works, but when i try to click the select list and change the value to Option 2 for example, it will revert back to Option 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED IT!

Got it to work by not doing any form_alter, instead i reconstructed the URL with the argument that sends me to the page view, with exactly the field_filter ID

So, basically, when you use exposed filters on a view, it automatically changes the url to something like `mysite.com/view?field_filter=1`, i tried to use `mysite.com/view?option=1` and then make a form alter to rewrite the `$form_state[input]`, but this will always overwrite the user POST.

Answer (score 3):

Use a custom module for this

```
function MYMODULE_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  if (!isset($form_state['view']->exposed_input['<filter_field>'])) {
    // OK to set the default value
    $form_state['input']['<filter_field>'] = '<new_default_value>';
  }
}
```

Where `filter_field` is the name of the exposed filter and `new_default_value` is the key of the value you want as the default.

Got the idea from this [article](http://venutip.com/content/setting-default-value-views-exposed-filters)

Comment: unfortunately this is basically the same thing, still did not reach my desired result. I've added an edit to elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

Working with `POST` values didn't work on my form.  And 4life's answer was close, but in the end this is the approach that worked for me complete with pretty paths:

```
    function MYMODULE_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
      $current_path = current_path();
      $path_array = explode('/', $current_path);
        if(isset($path_array[1])){
          switch ($path_array[1]) {
            case 'new_value':
              unset($form_state['input']['field_nameoffield']);
              $form_state['input']['field_nameoffield']['new_value']= 'new_value';
              break;

            case 'new_value_2':
              unset($form_state['input']['field_nameoffield']);
              $form_state['input']['field_nameoffield']['new_value_2']= 'new_value_2';
              break;
          }
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

As 4life specified in his answer, do this in a custom module in `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()`. The only difference is that you should set the `$form` element's `#default_value` property instead of injecting the default value into `$form_state['input']`. By doing that, you're overwriting whatever `$_POST` data the user has submitted.

Example:

```
<?php
function MYMODULE_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  if ($form_state['view']->name == 'your_view_name') {
    if (isset($_GET['option1'])) {
      $form['filter_field']['#default_value'] = $_GET['option1'];
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: tried this exactly how you specified, however the filter value in the select list does not change, I tried everything for the option (in the dpm($form) it shows me the new value, however the filter is not changing)

Comment: Same here ... filter does not change but $form value is updated

Comment: Modifying $form_state['input']['<filter_field>'] = '<default_value>'; did the trick for me.

One thing to keep in mind too ... if you let users select multiple options for hte field you want to add the default value, you should know that you have to add an array as a default value ... meaning criting somethinng like :  $form['filter_field']['#default_value'] = array(0 => 'All');

Answer (score 0):

Did you try some jquery to act on the href attribute of the button to rewrite the link that gives access to the page views, something like :

```
$(".my-button-class").each(function() {
$(this).attr("href", "/view-path?option=1");
});
```

Comment: Already tried to set the filter with jQuery, unfortunately I got the same behavior as setting the $form_state[input] value.